# How to concatenate a character to the values of columns in Java apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the values of a specific column say **`costs`**
 as

```
spark.select(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("costs") )
     .groupBy("col1")
     .agg( sum( col("costs") ) );
```

The output should have data of columns costs appended with `$` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) and [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit(java.lang.Object))

```
spark.select(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("costs") )
     .groupBy("col1")
     .agg( sum( col("costs") ).as("costs") )
     .withColumn("costs" , concat(lit("$") , col("costs")) ) ;
```